# LoadError for custom Ruby module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby. I am dealing with a codebase of the following nature.

I have a `main/` directory containing my entire codebase, and inside it I have files like:
`main/lib/foo/test1.rb` and
`main/app/bar/test2.rb`

Inside `main/app/bar/test2.rb` there is the line: `require 'test1'`

However, if I am in the `main/` directory and I run `ruby main/app/bar/test2.rb` I get the following error: `require': cannot load such file -- access_control (LoadError)`

Now, upon Googling, I think this has something to do with `/config/application.rb` and adding the line: `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib", "#{config.root}/lib/**/"`. I do this, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Presumably my production environment knows where to look in the `require 'test1.rb'` statement, while my environment does not. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `access_control` looks suspicious to me... could check file permissions and more of your console output here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a Ruby on Rails application.

Given that, you probably don't want to run any contained script directly with `ruby`. *If* it's designed to be executed directly, try running it with `rails runner path/to/file.rb` (from inside the directory that contains `app/`, `lib/`, `config/`, etc).

If it's inside `app/` or `lib/`, though, it's more likely intended to be loaded as a library from some other script elsewhere in the application... those would both be unusual places to keep a stand-alone executable.

Comment: So running `rails` just gives me a command not found, but yes, it is Ruby on Rails. What's going on here?

Regarding your second paragraph, do I take this to mean "forget about it"?

Comment: You could try `bundle exec rails [..]`, but it sound like you may not have Rails installed? Try `bundle install` first. The second point is more "check this is how the thing you're trying to load is intended to be run/used".